# How to calculate 95 percentile in Java using the datasets in Map

Tags: java, percentile

I am trying to calculate `95% percentile` from my datasets in Java. My datasets will have something like this-

I will be having a `ConcurrentHashMap` that will have key value pair like this-

```
Key = 30
Value = 10
```

which means 10 calls came back in 30 milliseconds

Another Example-

```
Key = 20
Value = 5
```

which means , 5 calls came back in 20 milliseconds

So from the above Map, I am trying to calculate 95% Percentile in Java.

Can anyone provide any example how to do that in Java from my above Map? Thanks for the help

**Updated Code:-**

Below is the code I have got which will calculate the 95th percentile from the Map-

```
/**
 * A simple method to log 95th percentile information
 */
private static void logPercentileInfo() {

    double total = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry : CassandraTimer.histogram.entrySet()) {
        long value = entry.getKey() * entry.getValue();
        total += value;
    }

    double sum = 0.95*total;

    double totalSum = 0;

    SortedSet<Long> keys = new TreeSet<Long>(CassandraTimer.histogram.keySet());
    for (long key : keys) {

        totalSum += CassandraTimer.histogram.get(key);

        if(totalSum >= sum) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone take a look and let me know whether I have written correctly?

Comment: What I have tried so far is on the Excel 2010 sheet with my datasets. And I am not sure how to do the same thing in java.

Comment: Is your question "I don't know how to do the math" or "I know how to do the math, but I don't know how to implement it in Java"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I know this is very old post. I have updated my question with the code I have written, Can you please take a look and let me know whether I have written correctly or not? I don't want to open a new post for the same question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please see this [related question][1] for a concise solution to this problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723766/calculating-average-from-a-histogram-map/30871423#30871423

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algorithm is: sum all values from your map, calculate 95% of the sum, iterate the map keys in ascending order keeping a running total of values, and when sum equals or exceeds the previously calculated 95% of the total sum, the key should be the 95th percentile.

Comment: I know this is very old post. I have written the code to calculate the percentile. Can you please take a look and let me know whether my code is correct or not? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Seems okay; but would it not be easier, not to mention more reliable to just compare the output of your code with the result that you get from Excel, where as I gather from your comments you know how to do it? (The only obvious thing would be to `break` or even better `return` out of the loop when you have your answer; as it is, you're printing all the values of the 95th percentile and above).

Answer (score 3):

You can also take a look at DescriptiveStatistics from Apache Commons

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html#getPercentile(double)

Comment: The DescriptiveStatistics class does not work on a histogram of the structure asked in the question.