# Calculating average and percentiles from a histogram map?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I have written a timer which will measure the performance of a particular code in any multithreaded application. In the below timer, it will also populate the map with how many calls took x milliseconds. I will use this map as part of my histogram to do further analysis, like what percentage of calls took this much milliseconds and etc.

```
public static class StopWatch {

    public static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long>();

    /**
     * Creates an instance of the timer and starts it running.
     */
    public static StopWatch getInstance() {
        return new StopWatch();
    }

    private long m_end = -1;
    private long m_interval = -1;
    private final long m_start;

    private StopWatch() {
        m_start = m_interval = currentTime();
    }

    /**
     * Returns in milliseconds the amount of time that has elapsed since the timer was created. If the
     * <code>stop</code> method has been invoked, then this returns instead the elapsed time between the creation of
     * the timer and the moment when <code>stop</code> was invoked.
     * 
     * @return duration it took
     */
    public long getDuration() {
        long result = 0;

        final long startTime = m_start;
        final long endTime = isStopWatchRunning() ? currentTime() : m_end;

        result = convertNanoToMilliseconds(endTime - startTime);

        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            Long oldValue = histogram.putIfAbsent(result, 1L);
            if (oldValue != null) {
                done = histogram.replace(result, oldValue, oldValue + 1);
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns in milliseconds the amount of time that has elapsed since the last invocation of this same method. If
     * this method has not previously been invoked, then it is the amount of time that has elapsed since the timer
     * was created. <strong>Note</strong> that once the <code>stop</code> method has been invoked this will just
     * return zero.
     * 
     * @return interval period
     */
    public long getInterval() {
        long result = 0;

        final long startTime = m_interval;
        final long endTime;

        if (isStopWatchRunning()) {
            endTime = m_interval = currentTime();
        } else {
            endTime = m_end;
        }

        result = convertNanoToMilliseconds(endTime - startTime);

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Stops the timer from advancing. This has an impact on the values returned by both the
     * <code>getDuration</code> and the <code>getInterval</code> methods.
     */
    public void stop() {
        if (isStopWatchRunning()) {
            m_end = currentTime();
        }
    }

    /**
     * What is the current time in nanoseconds?
     * 
     * @return returns back the current time in nanoseconds
     */
    private long currentTime() {
        return System.nanoTime();
    }

    /**
     * This is used to check whether the timer is alive or not
     * 
     * @return checks whether the timer is running or not
     */
    private boolean isStopWatchRunning() {
        return (m_end <= 0);
    }

    /**
     * This is used to convert NanoSeconds to Milliseconds
     * 
     * @param nanoseconds
     * @return milliseconds value of nanoseconds
     */
    private long convertNanoToMilliseconds(final long nanoseconds) {
        return nanoseconds / 1000000L;
    }
}
```

For example, this is the way I will use my above timer class to measure the performance of a particular code in my multithreading application:

```
StopWatch timer = StopWatch.getInstance();
//... some code here to measure
timer.getDuration();
```

Now my question is - What is the best way to calculate average, median, 95th and 99th percentile of the request from my histogram map? I mean to say, I want to add certain methods in my StopWatch class only which will does all the calculation like finding the average, median, 95th and 99th percentile.

And then I can just directly get it by using `StopWatch` instance.

My histogram map will look like this:

> key - means number of milliseconds
>
> value - means number of calls that took that much milliseconds.

Comment: Check this ---> http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879052/how-to-find-mean-and-median-from-histogram

Comment: Have you tried to code something?

Comment: Are you looking for a library that aids you with the statistical algorithms? Something like the statistics of [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html)?

Comment: @cheffe I have a histogram map and from that map, I need to calculate average, median, 95th and 99th percentile. If any library can do this, then it will be great otherwise what's the best way to do this manually in my `StopWatch` class?

Comment: Looks like there is a potential for race conditions in your code.  Between the call to `Long oldValue = histogram.putIfAbsent(result, 1L);` and `done = histogram.replace(result, oldValue, oldValue + 1);`, the values in the map could have changed.  Thus, `oldValue` could be stale

Comment: @XorProgramming  Yes but that's why I am looping right?

Comment: Ahh I see.  I was not familiar with the replace method that takes three parameters.  It seems to be ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mean is straightforward to implement. Median is the 50th percentile, so you just need a single percentile method that works, and create a utility method for the median. There are [several variations of Percentile calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#Microsoft_Excel_method), but this one should generate the same results as the Microsoft Excel PERCENTILE.INC function.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet;

public class HistogramStatistics
{
    public static Double average(final Map<Long, Long> histogram)
    {
        return HistogramStatistics.mean(histogram);
    }

    public static Double mean(final Map<Long, Long> histogram)
    {
        double sum = 0L;

        for (Long value : histogram.keySet())
        {
            sum += (value * histogram.get(value));
        }

        return sum / (double) HistogramStatistics.count(histogram);
    }

    public static Double median(final Map<Long, Long> histogram)
    {
        return HistogramStatistics.percentile(histogram, 0.50d);
    }

    public static Double percentile(final Map<Long, Long> histogram, final double percent)
    {
        if ((percent < 0d) || (percent > 1d))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Percentile must be between 0.00 and 1.00.");
        }

        if ((histogram == null) || histogram.isEmpty())
        {
            return null;
        }

        double n = (percent * (HistogramStatistics.count(histogram).doubleValue() - 1d)) + 1d;
        double d = n - Math.floor(n);
        SortedSet<Long> bins = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Long>(histogram.keySet());
        long observationsBelowBinInclusive = 0L;
        Long lowBin = bins.first();

        Double valuePercentile = null;

        for (Long highBin : bins)
        {
            observationsBelowBinInclusive += histogram.get(highBin);

            if (n <= observationsBelowBinInclusive)
            {
                if ((d == 0f) || (histogram.get(highBin) > 1L))
                {
                    lowBin = highBin;
                }

                valuePercentile = lowBin.doubleValue() + ((highBin - lowBin) * d);

                break;
            }

            lowBin = highBin;
        }

        return valuePercentile;
    }

    public static Long count(final Map<Long, Long> histogram)
    {
        long observations = 0L;

        for (Long value : histogram.keySet())
        {
            observations += histogram.get(value);
        }

        return observations;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a histogram (Frequency List) like the following

```
Value | Frequency
------+----------
    1 | 5
    2 | 3
    3 | 1
    4 | 7
    5 | 2
    ..
```

Where each `Value` has occurred `Frequency` times in your data-set.

```
public static double getMean (ConcurrentHashMap<Long,Long> histogram)
{
    double mean = 0;
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;

    TreeSet<Long> values = histogram.keySet();

    for (Long value : values)
    {
        // a = a + (value x frequency)
        a = a + (value * histogram.get(value));

        // b = b + frequency
        b = b + histogram.get(value);
    }

    // mean = SUM(value x frequency) / SUM(frequency)
    mean = (a / b);

    return mean;
}
```

Comment: This only answers (not even) half the question, which was about average *and percentiles*.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to round the measured duration to some desired resolution, e.g units of 10 or 100 milliseconds, so that your map will not get bloated with all possible latency values.

You can also use an array instead of a map for O(1) lookups in the worst case and memory locality advantage.

In addition, instead of the  `while (!done)` loop in `getDuration()`, you can use a [LongAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) or an [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) which should be faster.

As for reliably calculating a percentile over a binned histogram, you can look at [HBPE](https://github.com/IBM/HBPE) for a reference implementation. Disclaimer: I am the author.